# SQL- DDL command similar to DML delete command

Tags: sql, ddl, dml

Which SQL DDL command is analogous to the DML delete command? 
I think it's truncate but could it be drop?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your question really means.

Comment: Mureinik is correct. `TRUNCATE` wipes off the data in a table. `DELETE` can do that also, although there are [differences in what happens in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559893/comparison-of-truncate-vs-delete-in-mysql-sqlserver).

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`drop [something]` removes an object. `truncate` removes all the rows from a given table. In that sense, you could say it's analogous to a `delete` operation.

Answer (score 0):

*From MSDN:*

`DELETE` Removes one or more rows from a table or view in SQL Server.

`TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to the `DELETE` statement with no `WHERE` clause; however, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources.

Use `DROP` statements to remove existing entities. For example, use `DROP TABLE` to remove a table from a database.

Answer (score 0):

> **TRUNCATE Table** used to quickly delete all records in a table and
>   TRUNCATE Never changes the Structure Of a Table while it removes
>   table's data. It removes the spaces that we have allotted to table
>   records.
>
> **Drop** command is used to flush the table. Drop command is used when
>   we don't need the data.

Comment: Are you certain you want to state that `TRUNCATE TABLE` is DML? Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36607/why-is-truncate-ddl)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: @Morpheus: the SQL standard classifies TRUNCATE as a DML statement.