# How can I set my auto-increment value to start from 1 in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table. It had 1000+ products. I deleted all the products. Now, when I add any product, the product_id starts from above 1000. Is there any method to reset it to 1? I'm new to programming and databases. Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For your farther help, refer below link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559893/comparison-of-truncate-vs-delete-in-mysql-sqlserver>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the truncate table command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559893/comparison-of-truncate-vs-delete-in-mysql-sqlserver

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]simply do as per images given hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found it. It is in auto_increment field in operations.